# How to sync multiple calendars (Exchange/Google) on a Mac?

Tags: calendar, data-synchronization, ical

I have 2 calendars, connected to my Mac in iCal (but I am not wedded to that app);

- Work provided Exchange calendar
- My Google Calendar (also work, but provided by me)

I want to have both calendars in sync.. I like Google Calendar because I can use it over the web and I am just super happy and comfortable with it, I like the Exchange one to be in sync so everyone else can see my schedule.

I have another problem which I am trying to implicitly solve with this solution, and that is that invites no longer show up properly in GMail (they are plain text and I cannot "accept" them). They do show up however in my desktop mail app..

I would like to know if anyone have any ideas of an app for Mac/OSX (or even an online service) that can keep both calendars in sync (even with some restriction) with minimal ongoing manual work? I've Googled for a few hours with no result..

Thanks a lot in advance..

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

[Spanning Sync](http://spanningsync.com/) ($25/year) should do this. However, when I tried to use it I kept getting a crash (version 3.2/443).

[BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/) ($39.99) should also do this [edit: I just got a note from BusySync support saying that this does not work for Exchange].

> You may now add and edit events, in iCal or Google, on any of the calendars you published or subscribed to, and the events will sync in both directions between iCal and Google.

However, when I set up my Exchange calendar to publish to Google, and modified the calendar inside the Google Calendar interface, the new modifications get clobbered the next time BusySync syncs. It does at least successfully publish the events on Google Calendar, though.